# Using residue theorem, evaluate the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Using the residue calculus, evaluate the integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{x^{1/3}(x^2-1)} dx$

I know, that the function has singularities at +1, -1, 0. I find the rule which says that:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) ln(x) dx = -\frac{1}{2}Re \sum\limits_{C-[0;{\infty})} res_z(f(z)log_{2\pi}^{2}z)$

I need help at the moment because I don't get the right result and I don't know where I could have made a mistake and if this rule can be used.

Comment: I got that the integral is π^2/3 from Wolfram.

Comment: It keeps changing values for my from wolfram

Comment: the result is indeed $\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$, i was able to prove this without complex analysis, would you like me to post such solution?

Comment: It would be useful to show your approach. It is hard to say what is your mistake without this.